# Elementary row operations give different solution set

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**Question:** Find the values of $b$ in which the linear system has no solutions, one solution, or infinitely many solutions

$$x + 2y +z = 2$$

$$2x-2y+3z =1$$

$$x+2y+(b^2-3)z=b$$

---

So I simplified the corresponding augmented matrix to
$$(1)$$

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 2 & 1 & 2 \\
        0 & 1 & -\frac{1}{4} & \frac{3}{4}\\
        0 & 0 & 4-b^2 & 2-b\\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Simplifying again then becomes (REF)
$$(2)$$

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 2 & 1 & 2 \\
        0 & 1 & -\frac{1}{4} & \frac{3}{4}\\
        0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{1}{2+b}\\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Now,

- if $b \neq -2$, then  the system has **one solution** (back substitution)
- if $b=-2$, then the system has **no solution** (last row will become $z=\frac{1}{0}$)

However, my solution is slightly wrong as the correct answer should be

- if $b \neq ±2$, then  the system has **one solution**
- if $b=-2$, then the system has **no solution**
- if $b=2$, then the system has **infinitely many solutions**

The reason for this is that the $b$ values were evaluated in the matrix $(1)$ not $(2)$, so I am not sure whether I should continue simplifying the matrix or stop at $(1)$. So my question is why is my answer not correct even though it makes sense? (by the way my matrix is correct so there's no arithmetic errors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From (1) to (2), you divided both $4-b^2$ and $2-b$ by $4-b^2$.

However, when $4-b^2 = 0$, this division is not valid, so the cases $b = \pm2$ need to be considered seperately.

In particular, for $b = 2$, the last row of $(1)$ is all zeros.

This implies that there are infinitely many solutions.

Comment: I understand your answer, but why do I only consider $b=2$ for $(1)$ and not $(2)$? The function specifically is $\frac{1}{2+b},b≠±2$ due to the hole at $b = 2$ and vertical asymptote at $b = -2$. If I now plug $b=2$ in $(2)$ I would get $z=1/4$ which does not represent infinite solutions

Comment: You cannot divide both sides by $4 -b^2$ if $b = \pm 2$. Your division is only valid for $b \ne \pm2$.

Comment: Is there  a way of getting the correct answer using $(2)$ instead of $(1)$?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, since $(2)$ and $(1)$ are different systems of equations. (esp. for $b = \pm2$).

Comment: Is there a reason why I should not use $(2)$ besides getting different systems? It makes sense since I am reducing it to REF though.

Comment: I thought elementary operations don't change the solutio nset

Comment: As I have said, you are dividing by zero.

Comment: I am multiplying the last row by a nonzero number which should not change the solution set. Since the nonzero number $\frac{1}{4-b^2}$ could be zero, rewriting it as $\frac{1}{4-b^2}, b≠±2$ should remove the case of division by zero but I still get an incorrect solution set

Comment: Then you need to consider the cases $b = \pm 2$ separately because of your assumption. That is, you can ONLY use $(2)$ for the cases $b \ne \pm2$, but you must resort to using $(1)$ for the cases $b =\pm2 $.

Comment: As a side note, $\dfrac 1 {4-b^2}$ cannot be zero. It is undefined for $4-b^2=0$.

Comment: Ok so from $(1)$ to $(2)$ I am multiplying the last row by $\frac{1}{4-b^2}, b≠±2$ which turns the last row into $z=\frac{1}{2+b}$. Given that this nonzero number multiplied to the last row is defined only when $b≠±2$, $(2)$ simply has one solution when $b≠±2$. When considering $b=±2$, then refer back to $(1)$ as there is no restriction, which then gives the result: $b=2=>$ $(0=0)$ infinite solutions, $b=-2=>$ $(0=4)$ no solutions. Is this  the way?

Comment: Yep you got it.

Comment: Alright thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

This is because $\frac{2-b}{4-b^2}\neq\frac{1}{2+b}$ when $b=2$ (it's actually indeterminate). So we need to inspect the solution b=2 individually.

If we plug in $b=2$ into (1), we get a bottom row of zeros, which means $z$ is a free variable and hence infinite solutions.

In conclusion, $b=2$ yields a row of zeros hence infinite solutions; $b=-2$ yields something like $0=1$ hence no solutions; and anything else should have 1 solution.

Comment: Not sure if I understand but $\frac{2-b}{4-b^2}$ ≠ $\frac{1}{2+b}$ because $\frac{1}{2+b}$  as a function is the graph of $\frac{2-b}{4-b^2}$ but with a hole at $b=2$. So then that creates an additional case to consider: $b≠2$ and $b=2$. But now I'm not sure about when $b=2$, because now the bottom row from $(2)$ would then be $z=1/4$ which does not mean infinite solutions

Comment: @user314 The problem is that once you cross out the $(2-b)$'s to get (2), you are not allowed to plug in $b=2$ into the new equation. This is because by crossing out the $(2-b)$'s you have removed $b=2$ from the domain to preserve equality.

Comment: I am getting confused. Besides obtaining the row corresponding to 0 = 0 by substituting in $b=2$ in $(1)$ why is $b=2$ not listed as no solution instead? $b = -2$ is undefined due to a vertical asymptote and $b=2$ is also undefined due to a hole, so wouldn't this mean that $b=±2$ gives no solutions?

Comment: I guess if I used $(1)$ instead of $(2)$ the correct answer would easily be obtained. But is there any way to obtain the same answer from $(2)$? I feel like substituting $b=2$ back in $(1)$ after simplifying to $(2)$ does not seem right mathematically

Comment: I don't think there is anyway to obtain the same answer because by making that step, you have removed a possible value of x to be considered in the domain. I get what you mean by it not seeming right mathematically. Similar problems that appear in competition math are algebra questions where you have something like a sum of 2 squareroot terms is equal to another square root (hopefully that makes sense). One approach to these types of problems is to square everything, manipulate, and square again to get a quartic. However, when doing this you are adding to the domain of x, so you have to go...

Comment: back and check each of the 4 solutions to make sure none of them are extraneous. I always made the mistake to not check back, and I felt the same thing as you, that it doesn't seem right that I have to go back and check that my answers are right even if all the steps I made are mathematically valid. However, whenever you make a step that changes the domain (either removes elements like in your case or adds them like in my case), it is best to make sure that whatever solutions you get still work in the original equation. And check if any elements you removed may also be a solution.